# Problems using ErrorDocument httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

Using the httpd.conf file*, I hope to create ErrorDocument handlers that redirect the user to a certain website. The code on the error page is:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/?error=true");
?>
```

I'm using the syntax: ErrorDocument 404 /error.php, and error.php is in the same directory as the httpd.conf file. After restarting my server, the error 404 page says
"Not Found

The requested URL /404page was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

What path should I use?
*I want to use the httpd.conf file, not .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

read here about http status codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

```
# Some examples:
ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting the file in a directory relative to the httpd.conf file:
ErrorDocument 404 /error/index.php